# calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function

Tags: cuda, nvcc

When compiling the MWE

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda.h"

struct Foo{
///*
    Foo( ){
      std::cout << "Construct" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo( const Foo & that ){
      std::cout << "Copy construct" << std::endl;
    }
//*/
   __host__ __device__
   int bar( ) const {
     return 0;
   }
};

template<typename CopyBody>
__global__ 
void kernel( CopyBody cBody ){
  cBody( );
}

template <typename CopyBody>
void wrapper( CopyBody && cBody ){
  std::cout << "enquing kernel" << std::endl;
  kernel<<<1,32>>>( cBody );
  std::cout << "kernel enqued" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  Foo foo;

  std::cout << "enquing kernel" << std::endl;
  kernel<<<1,32>>>( [=] __device__ ( ) { foo.bar( ); } );
  std::cout << "kernel enqued" << std::endl;
  cudaDeviceSynchronize( );

  wrapper( [=] __device__ ( ) { foo.bar( ); } );
  cudaDeviceSynchronize( );
  
  return 0;
}
```

with CUDA 10.1 (`nvcc --expt-extended-lambda test.cu -o test`) the compiler warns about `test.cu(16): warning: calling a __host__ function("Foo::Foo") from a __host__ __device__ function("") is not allowed`. However, the copy constructor is never called on the device. CUDA 9.1 does not produce this warning.

- What is the difference between the direct call to `kernel` (not producing the warning) and the `wrapper` version?
- Is is safe to ignore this warning?
- Where to put `#pragma hd_warning_disable` or `#pragma nv_exec_check_disable` to get rid of it?

The given MWE is a based on a larger project, where the `wrapper` decides whether to use a `__device__` or `__host__` lambda. The constructors/destructors cannot be marked as `__host__ __device__` since they need to be called on CPU only ((de)allocating CUDA memory) - this or deleting the constructors/destructor (and letting the compilers to create the default `__host__` and `__device__` versions) would otherwise help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem? I would be interested in it.

Comment: Not really. I just marked the ctor/dtor as `__host__ __device__` and `assert(0)` when called on the device (i.e. if `__CUDA_ARCH__ is defined).

Answer (score 1):

With the following modifications I don't get mentioned warnings: ( I used CUDA 10.1 on Windows 10 )

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

struct Baz {

   Baz() {
      printf("%s: Construct\n", __FUNCTION__);
   }

   Baz(const Baz & that) {
      printf("%s: Copy Construct\n", __FUNCTION__);
   }

};

struct Foo: 
   public Baz {

   __host__ __device__ 
   int bar() const  {
      return 0;
   } 
};

template<typename CopyBody>
__global__
void kernel(CopyBody cBody) {
   cBody();
}

template <typename CopyBody>
void wrapper(CopyBody && cBody) {
   printf("%s: enquing kernel\n",__FUNCTION__);
   kernel << <1, 32 >> > (cBody);
   printf("%s: kernel enqued\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   Foo foo;

   printf("%s: enquing kernel\n", __FUNCTION__);   
   kernel << <1, 32 >> > ([=] __device__() { foo.bar(); });
   printf("%s: kernel enqued\n", __FUNCTION__);   
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();

   wrapper([=] __device__() { foo.bar(); });
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();

   return 0;
}
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
Foo::Foo: Construct
main: enquing kernel
Foo::Foo: Copy Construct
Foo::Foo: Copy Construct
main: kernel enqued
Foo::Foo: Copy Construct
Foo::Foo: Copy Construct
wrapper: enquing kernel
Foo::Foo: Copy Construct
wrapper: kernel enqued
```

I replaced `<iostream>` with `<stdio.h`> for convenience. `printf()` works from the kernel.

Comment: Hi, thanks. However, as I've described above, the constructors/destructors cannot be marked as `__host__ __device__` since they need to be called on CPU only ((de)allocating CUDA memory).

Comment: Hi Jan, I verified that the ctors were not called on the device, despite the markings. Anyway, I rearranged the code in order to make sure the ctors are called on the CPU only.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the effort, but unfortunately the post does not answer any of the questions.

Comment: Jan, your questions are irrelevant IMHO. 1) assumes the direct call produces warnings, the wrapped call does not. This is not the case. 2) After fixing the code there are no warnings to ignore. 3) You don't need those pragmas to ignore the non-existing warnings.

Comment: Laszlo, I am sorry, but have you actually read the question as a whole? I CANNOT mark the ctor as a `_device_` function, as it calls CUDA memory allocation. The presented code is just a MWE to see the warnings. Also, there are certain aspects I do not fully understand, like the number of times the copy ctor is called.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your last sentence. Answers don't come most probably because nobody really understands what you mean.  To find out when the copy constructors are called, put a breakpoint on them and check the call stack. For me it shows, that the copy constructor is called whenever foo is passed as an argument (as expected). I noticed a difference between running the unoptimized code in Debug mode and optimized code running in Release mode. The latter behaves much like you describe, where the "difference" between the direct call and calling the wrapper is optimized away.